# Counting factor observation via aggregate in R

Tags: r, aggregate

My vector is

```
 Name
  s1
  s1
  s1
  s2
  s2
  s3
```

I need to count number of occurrences of each value. The expected output is something like this

```
 Names  No.
 s1      3
 s2      2
 s3      1
```

I am using aggregate function for that which is

```
aggregate(case2$Name,by=list(Names =case2$Name),table)
```

It gives me the correct result but in diagnol matrix form instead of another vector as in my expected output.

If I try aggregate function with count, as like here

```
aggregate(case2$Name,by=list(Names =case2$Name),count)
```

It gives me this error

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

not sure what shall I do with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed that `table(Name)` is the most straight forward approach but for reference the correct syntax for using `aggregate` to get the same result is:

`aggregate(Name, by=list(Name), length)`

Comment: thanks , I never knew before that also counts the length of Factors within vectors as well.

Comment: @user3050590 You can even do a table on a table, `table(table(Name))`, which is something I've done before for some funky stratified sampling strategy, I wanted to see how uniform the sampling was.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple call to table, something like

```
table(Name)
```

For your example, you'll find something like...

```
> Name = as.factor( c ( 's1' , 's1' , 's1' , 's2' , 's2' , 's3' ) )
> Name
[1] s1 s1 s1 s2 s2 s3
Levels: s1 s2 s3
> table(Name)
Name
s1 s2 s3
 3  2  1


> t <- table(Name)
> str(t)
 'table' int [1:3(1d)] 3 2 1
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ Name: chr [1:3] "s1" "s2" "s3"
> t[1]
s1 
 3 
> t[2]
s2 
 2 
> t[3]
s3 
 1 
> t['s1']
s1 
 3 

> str(t['s1'])
 Named int 3
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "s1"

> sprintf( "abcd = %d" , t[1] )
[1] "abcd = 3"
> t[1] + 5
s1 
 8
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @jxramos works perfectly, but the `table` format can sometimes be slightly inconvenient. Data stored in matrices, dataframes, or vectors are usually somewhat easier to handle. 
If you want a matrix as an output (with one column in this case, so it is essentially a vector), you could perform a minor modification like this:

```
v1 <- c ('s1' , 's1' , 's1' , 's2' , 's2' , 's3' ) 
v2 <- as.matrix(table(v1))
colnames(v2) <- "Name"
```

This is the output:

```
> v2
   Name
s1    3
s2    2
s3    1
```